# From Container View to go another container view in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, containers, segue

I try,  http://kodesnippets.com/index.php/2015/08/11/container-view-in-ios/ tutorial and I downloaded GitHub project , but I didn't do ,

> From First Container , to go second container view with button action

my codes under below.

I added only

`FirstViewController` inside

```
 var container: ContainerViewController!

  @IBAction func test(_ sender: UIButton) {


       container!.segueIdentifierReceivedFromParent("second")


    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "container"{

            container = segue.destination as! ContainerViewController


        }
    }
```

And I linked button action to test. When I clicked it gives me;

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

error in this line, and didn't go to second view controller

```
container!.segueIdentifierReceivedFromParent("second")
```

Any idea ? also GitHub link under below.

https://github.com/iaaqib/ContainerView

Answer (score 0):

The variable container isn't setup to point to anything.

Comment: I added only that codes and I linked button action.

Comment: Ignore my previous response about ctrl dragging, was talking rubbish. Have you setup the embedded segue to be called "container"? If not the code in prepare() won't setup container

Answer (score 0):

There is no any segue from FirstViewController, so `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` method is not called and that's the reason why container property is nil.